# External injected global variable

Tags: perl, global-variables

How can an external injected global variable be accessed simply by its name?

That snippet does not work without fully qualifying the variable:

```
#! /bin/perl

use strict; use warnings;

package Haus;

sub test{
        print __PACKAGE__."\n";

        # Works
        print "qualified var [$Haus::var]\n"; # OK

        # not working, why and how to achieve that without
        # local "our $var" instead external injected
        print "simple var [$var]\n"; # NOK
}

package main;

$Haus::var=1;
Haus::test();
```

Comment: Inside `Haus` there is no difference between `$Haus::var` and `$var`.

Answer (score 2):

I think, that you got a compile time error because stricture is enabled and `$var` is not declared in your example. Declare the variable with `our` so that Perl knows that you mean `$Haus::var`.  See [our](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/our)

Comment: perl always defaults to `our` (package variable) when not explicitly given type of variable.

Comment: @mpapec is right, I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You (appropriately) asked Perl to not let you use `$var` without first declaring `$var`.

> **`strict vars`**
>
> This generates a compile-time error if you access a variable that was neither explicitly declared (using any of `my`, `our`, `state`, or `use vars`) nor fully qualified. (Because this is to avoid variable suicide problems and subtle dynamic scoping issues, a merely `local` variable isn't good enough.) See "my" in perlfunc, "our" in perlfunc, "state" in perlfunc, "local" in perlfunc, and vars.

All you need to do is declare `$var`. Both `our $var;` and `use vars qw( $var );` would do the trick here.

You could also remove the request (by using `use strict; no strict qw( vars );`), but there's no reason to do that, and plenty not to.